# How to pass the parameters to include in URL?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

In the repository class of WebApi project there is the method `GetSingleIncluding()` that returns an entity with indluded objects that were passed as parameters.

```
private readonly EFDbContext _context;
private IDbSet<T> _entities;            
private IDbSet<T> Entities
{
    get
    {
        _entities = _entities ?? _context.Set<T>();
        return _entities;
    }
}               
public T GetSingleIncluding(int id, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includeProperties)
{
    var query = Entities.Where(x => x.ID == id);

    foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties)
    {
        query = query.Include(includeProperty);
    }

    return query.First();
}
```

I have an action in a controller

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetFull(int id, string entities)
```

I use it as:

```
var entitiy = Repository.GetSingleIncluding(id, x => x.Person);
```

here I pass explicitly a parameter `x => x.Persons`

Is there any way to pass this parameters by url request? E.g I will pass all objects (that can be include for the current entity) as string in the url

```
http://localhost/api/House/1/Person,Address,...
```

and the controller will be pass these params to the `GetSingleIncluding()` method:

```
Repository.GetSingleIncluding(id, x => x.Person, y => y.Address);
```

House entity

```
public class House : BaseEntity
{
        public int PersonID { get; set; }
        public int HouseID { get; set; }
        public int AddressID { get; set; }
        ...
        public virtual Person Person { get; set; }        
        public virtual Address Address { get; set; }
 }
```

Comment: First, i don't believe that is possible. You can put primitive values in your querystring, but not an `Expression`. You might be able to do something crazy with Reflection, but I must question the use case where the web browser is dictating what EF navigation properties should be included. Your UI should have no idea about your data layer.

Comment: I do not want to put Expression in qury string. It should be just a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Agree with Mister Epic, I think it is not a good idea getting the "includes" from the url. Any way, you can pass to your method an array of strings:

```
public T GetSingleIncluding(int id, string[] includeProperties)
{
    var query = Entities.Where(x => x.ID == id);

    if (includeProperties != null && includeProperties.Count() > 0)
    {
        query = query.Include(includes.First());
        foreach (var include in includeProperties.Skip(1))
            query = query.Include(include);
    }

    return query.First();
}
```

You need to add this "using":

```
using System.Data.Entity;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at odata.It has build in capabilities for adding includes. Take a look at this [link](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/using-select-expand-and-value) and read about the $expand parameter.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I know about it and use in other project. In this project I can not use OData